# Https causing redirect loop?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, https

I am using code igniter, our server is behind some funky config.

I want certian pages to be behind https, certian pages to be behind http, and others I don't care about.

So below is my setup,

- If I go to `http://test.example.com` (which has a call to `disable_ssl()`) the page loads fine
- If I go to `https://test.example.com/login` (which has a call to `require_ssl()`) the page loads fine.
- If I go the `http://test.example.com/login` I get redirected to the https version. which is good.
- If I go to `https://test.example.com` then I get hit with a redirect loop...
  For some reason the header keeps getting set to `https` instead of `http`, even though I explicitly write `http`.

My `$_SERVER` array on an http request looks like looks like

```
Array
(
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [HTTP_HOST] => test.example.com:80
    [HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => 119.224.22.142
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 119.224.22.142
    [HTTP_X_URL_SCHEME] => http
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.100 Safari/534.30
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,sdch
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8,en-NZ;q=0.6
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => [...]
    [PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at test.example.com Port 8080


    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
    [SERVER_NAME] => test.example.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [SERVER_PORT] => 8080
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/index.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 54833
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PATH_INFO] => /
    [PATH_TRANSLATED] => redirect:/index.php/
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php/
    [PHP_AUTH_USER] => ******
    [PHP_AUTH_PW] => ******
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1308972068
)
```

and on a https request it looks like

```
Array
(
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [HTTP_HOST] => test.example.com:443
    [HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => 119.224.22.142
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 119.224.22.142
    [HTTP_X_URL_SCHEME] => https
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => https
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.100 Safari/534.30
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,sdch
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8,en-NZ;q=0.6
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => [...]
    [PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at test.example.com Port 8080


    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
    [SERVER_NAME] => test.example.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [SERVER_PORT] => 8080
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/index.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 54841
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PATH_INFO] => /
    [PATH_TRANSLATED] => redirect:/index.php/
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php/
    [PHP_AUTH_USER] => ********
    [PHP_AUTH_PW] => ********
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1308972250
)
```

and my .htaccess looks like

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|css|images|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

So at the very top of my index.php I have

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = explode(':', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'][0];
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'][1];
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
  $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'On';
else
  $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'Off';
```

And on pages where I want HTTPS I call

```
function require_ssl(){
    if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'Off') {
        $host = explode(':', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        header('location: https://' . $host[0] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit;
    }
}
```

And on pages where I want only HTTP I call

```
function disable_ssl(){
    if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'On') {
        $host = explode(':', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        header('location: http://' . $host[0] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you turn on rewrite logging at a 3+ level (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) it'll show you exactly what the engine is doing to the requested url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after hours of painful debugging we finally worked out the issue.

**Nginx**
Yep, the load balancer was doing it's own redirects.

In the *nginx* setup this line existed `proxy_redirect http:// https://;`

So, what was happening?

Well,
My code was saying "this page should not be https, redirect"
Then *nginx* was saying "this request is not https, redirect"
Then my code was...
**boom** redirect loop.

So, by changing `proxy_redirect http:// https://;` to `proxy_redirect Off;` we fixed the problem :)

Comment: We've addressed the accurate fix for Nginx here http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/magento-https-redirect-loop/ This avoids the necessity to have that code in your `index.php` file

Comment: @Hailwood : I'm facing the same issue. My login page must be https but it is getting redirected to http. But my proxy_redirect is already set to off. Any ideas on how I could further investigate?

Comment: @Hailwood : Hi, I am faing the same issue, after I installed ssl certificate i cannot access the Admin Panel and the page goes in a redirect loop,  Can U tell me where do i make the above changes ?

Answer (score 1):

The function that you posted for `disable_ssl()` shows:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '0n') {
```

Is the `0` ('zero') a copy/paste error? I assume that you meant:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'On') {
```

If I'm following your logic correctly, this function is invoked when you goto `https://test.example.com`, and so if this typo exists, it is probably not doing what you think it should.

Comment: Heh, Yes thats just a typo on here, I will fix that (I edited the question a bit later).

Answer (score 1):

We've addressed the accurate fix for Nginx (and other reverse proxies) here:

**http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/magento-https-redirect-loop/**

This avoids the necessity to have that code in your `index.php` file. All you needed to do was add this to your Nginx config,

```
fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using .htaccess rules instead, something like:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (optional pattern additional url matching)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.example.com/$1 [L]
```

if you want to force http just replace 80 with 443 and https with http.

Comment: I had thought about that, but this gives me more control, as I can enable/disable ssl when I need to.